# Start Tomcat as a Windows service with Security Manager

Tags: tomcat

To start Tomcat with Security Manager from command line, we do:

```
bin\catalina.bat start -security
```

I'm trying to do the similar for Tomcat Service which by default call without security manager:

```
bin\tomcat6.exe" //RS//Tomcat6
```

Anybody knows how to start the service with security?

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer for my question: after installing Tomcat as a service, run `bin\tomcat6w.exe`. Under Java tab, add these 2 lines:

```
-Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy=[tomcat_dir]\conf\catalina.policy
```

If you install the service by your script, add the above lines with `++JvmOptions` (see http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html)

```
...\Tomcat6.exe //US//Tomcat6 ++JvmOptions=-Djava.security.manager;-Djava.security.policy=...
```

Comment: Note the subtle difference between using single and double equals in `-Djava.security.policy`. See [Security Developer’s Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/permissions-java-development-kit.htm#GUID-BFF84712-05CF-4C1E-926F-411FDF83AE32). `catalina.sh` uses double equals to configure *only* `catalina.policy` as the policy file